# Escalar imagen de fondo manteniendo aspecto

Tags: html, html5, css, bootstrap, css3

Estoy creando una galería de imágenes adaptativa en el que se muestran miniaturas de la imagen en cuadrados. Para ello pongo las imágenes de fondo usando `background-image` y para que la imagen ocupe todo el cuadrado, uso `background-size:cover`.

Esto funciona independientemente del tamaño de la imagen (las diferentes imágenes de fondo tendrán diferentes tamaños) y las imágenes se ajustan al tamaño del div contenedor sin problemas:

```css
#gallery .squared { 
  height:0; 
  padding-top:50%; 
  background:#ab00ff; 
  position:relative; 
  color:white; 
  font-size:1.2em; 
  background-position:center center; 
  background-size:cover; 
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
  #gallery .squared { padding-top:25%; }
}

@media (min-width: 992px) {
  #gallery .squared { padding-top:16.66%; }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<section id="gallery" class="section container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="squared col-xs-6 col-sm-3 col-md-2" style="background-image:url(http://lorempixel.com/300/200/people);"></div>
    <div class="squared col-xs-6 col-sm-3 col-md-2" style="background-image:url(http://lorempixel.com/300/300/nature);"></div>
    <div class="squared col-xs-6 col-sm-3 col-md-2" style="background-image:url(http://lorempixel.com/300/500/cats);"></div>
    <div class="squared col-xs-6 col-sm-3 col-md-2" style="background-image:url(http://lorempixel.com/500/300/sports);"></div>
    <div class="squared col-xs-6 col-sm-3 col-md-2" style="background-image:url(http://lorempixel.com/300/200/abstract);"></div>
    <div class="squared col-xs-6 col-sm-3 col-md-2" style="background-image:url(http://lorempixel.com/300/400/animals);"></div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Ahora quiero añadir algo de animación y que cuando el usuario mueva el ratón por encima de los cuadrados la imagen de fondo crezca un poco, por ejemplo un 10%. Pero no encuentro manera de hacerlo. He intentado cambiando el valor de `background-size` a 100% y en el `:hover` a 110%, pero no funciona bien porque ese porcentaje es con respecto al contenedor y no al tamaño de la imagen, por lo que, aunque el efecto funciona, las imágenes apaisadas no terminan de verse bien (se ven repetidas):

```css
#gallery .squared { 
  height:0; 
  padding-top:50%; 
  background:#ab00ff; 
  position:relative; 
  color:white; 
  font-size:1.2em; 
  background-position:center center; 
  background-size:100%; 
  transition:all 1s;
}

#gallery .squared:hover { 
  background-size:110%; 
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
  #gallery .squared { padding-top:25%; }
}

@media (min-width: 992px) {
  #gallery .squared { padding-top:16.66%; }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<section id="gallery" class="section container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="squared col-xs-6 col-sm-3 col-md-2" style="background-image:url(http://lorempixel.com/300/200/people);"></div>
    <div class="squared col-xs-6 col-sm-3 col-md-2" style="background-image:url(http://lorempixel.com/300/300/nature);"></div>
    <div class="squared col-xs-6 col-sm-3 col-md-2" style="background-image:url(http://lorempixel.com/300/500/cats);"></div>
    <div class="squared col-xs-6 col-sm-3 col-md-2" style="background-image:url(http://lorempixel.com/500/300/sports);"></div>
    <div class="squared col-xs-6 col-sm-3 col-md-2" style="background-image:url(http://lorempixel.com/300/200/abstract);"></div>
    <div class="squared col-xs-6 col-sm-3 col-md-2" style="background-image:url(http://lorempixel.com/300/400/animals);"></div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Para evitar que se repita podría hacer algo como `background-repeat: no-repeat` pero eso no es lo que quiero porque se verían espacios en blanco en algunas cuadrados.

Así que la pregunta sería: ¿Es posible hacer esto exclusivamente con HTML y CSS **sin utilizar JavaScript**?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Una solución rápida que se me ocurre es usando `::before`, esos pseudo-elementos pueden ayudar mucho en algunos casos (como este). Es algo 'hackish' pero puede darte una idea.

Podrías usar el `::before` con visibilidad en hidden o en visible, en este último caso no necesitarías la imagen de fondo que declaras en el estilo inline de cada div de la galería.

Una desventaja es que el `::before` no lo puedes utilizar en un estilo inline, tendrías que agregar un `<style>...</style>` para cada div en caso que los estés generando con un loop o similar.

```css
#gallery .squared { 
  height:0; 
  padding-top:50%; 
  background:#ab00ff; 
  position:relative; 
  color:white; 
  font-size:1.2em; 
  background-position:center center; 
  background-size:cover; 
  transition:all 1s;
  overflow:hidden;
}

#gallery .squared::before {
  background-image:url(http://lorempixel.com/300/200/people);
  content: " ";
  height:100%;
  width:100%;
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  background-size:cover;
  visibility:hidden; /* puede ser visible también */
}

#gallery .squared:hover::before {
  background-image:url(http://lorempixel.com/300/200/people);
  height:110%;
  width:110%;
  content: " ";  
  position:absolute;
  top:-5%;
  left:-5%;
  transition:all 1s;
  visibility:visible;
}

#gallery .squared:hover { 
  background-size:110%; 
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
  #gallery .squared { padding-top:25%; }
}

@media (min-width: 992px) {
  #gallery .squared { padding-top:16.66%; }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<section id="gallery" class="section container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="squared col-xs-6 col-sm-3 col-md-2" style="background-image:url(http://lorempixel.com/300/200/people);"></div>
    <div class="squared col-xs-6 col-sm-3 col-md-2" style="background-image:url(http://lorempixel.com/300/300/nature);"></div>
    <div class="squared col-xs-6 col-sm-3 col-md-2" style="background-image:url(http://lorempixel.com/300/500/cats);"></div>
    <div class="squared col-xs-6 col-sm-3 col-md-2" style="background-image:url(http://lorempixel.com/500/300/sports);"></div>
    <div class="squared col-xs-6 col-sm-3 col-md-2" style="background-image:url(http://lorempixel.com/300/200/abstract);"></div>
    <div class="squared col-xs-6 col-sm-3 col-md-2" style="background-image:url(http://lorempixel.com/300/400/animals);"></div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta. Me sirvió de ayuda y base para lo que acabé haciendo al final.

Answer (score 3):

Yo tengo una alternativa y explico mis razones.

La parte que no me gusta de usar `:before` para esta tarea es que es muy complicado estilar los elementos cuando la url de las imagenes aún no es conocida.

No deberías cambiar el estilo `background-size: cover` ya que este te va a dar el mejor ajuste de las imagenes posible así que tanto mostrar la imagen como para animarla debe dejar esta propiedad como está.

Esto es a tu gusto pero prefiero usar [`transform`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/transform) con `transform: scale(X)` en lugar de cambiar `width: 110%`, `height: 110%` o `background-size: 110%`, es menos compatible pero la razon es que cuando usas dimensiones es mas complicado controlar el origen de la animación. Animando con `transform: scale` siempre lo hará desde el centro y si quieres cambiar eso puedes usar [`transform-origin`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/transform-origin). Si usas dimensiones tendrás que ajustar constantemente `left`, `top`, etc dependiendo del estilo que hayas escogido.

Para lograr lo que quieres simplemente crea un elemento nuevo dentro de cada uno de tus divs con clase `.squared`. Yo use la clase `.thumb`. Usar `position: absolute` es obligatorio ya que el elemento `.squared` esta colapsado con `height: 0` pero ya que el contenedor tiene `position: relative` no hay riesgo que se salga de su lugar. Esto tiene exactamente el mismo efecto que usar `:before` pero sin los problemas que este acarrea y tienes más libertad para usar estilos inline.

Chequea el demo que te dejo.

```css
#gallery .squared {
  height: 0;
  padding-top: 50%;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}
#gallery .squared .thumb {
  position: absolute;
  background-size: cover;
  transition: all 1s;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
#gallery .squared .thumb:hover {
  transform: scale(1.5);
}
#gallery .squared:hover {
  background-size: 110%;
}
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  #gallery .squared {
    padding-top: 25%;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 992px) {
  #gallery .squared {
    padding-top: 16.66%;
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<section id="gallery" class="section container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="squared col-xs-6 col-sm-3 col-md-2">
      <div class="thumb" style="background-image:url(http://lorempixel.com/300/200/people);"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="squared col-xs-6 col-sm-3 col-md-2">
      <div class="thumb" style="background-image: url(http://lorempixel.com/300/300/nature);"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="squared col-xs-6 col-sm-3 col-md-2">
      <div class="thumb" style="background-image: url(http://lorempixel.com/300/500/cats);"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="squared col-xs-6 col-sm-3 col-md-2">
      <div class="thumb" style="background-image: url(http://lorempixel.com/500/300/sports);"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="squared col-xs-6 col-sm-3 col-md-2">
      <div class="thumb" style="background-image: url(http://lorempixel.com/300/200/abstract);"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="squared col-xs-6 col-sm-3 col-md-2">
      <div class="thumb" style="background-image: url(http://lorempixel.com/300/400/animals);"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Ahora puedes reusar este snipet de css sin tener que modificar una línea de código, solo tienes que cambiar las urls de tus imagenes, lo cual puedes lograr fácilmente con un repeater en el lenguaje que estés usando.

Comment: Esta solución se ve bien. Lo único que le cambiaría: no hace falta ponerle imagen de fondo al `div` con clase "squared" porque el que tiene clase "thumb" lo esconde.

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro Cierto, la clase `.squared` solo actúa como un marco para las fotos. Mala mía al copiar el html para la respuesta. Usé tu ejemplo inicial para agregar los estilos y olvidé eliminar esa parte. Enseguida lo actualizo.

Answer (score 1):

Gracias a la [respuesta de Shaz](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/9844/250), pude encontrar una manera de hacerlo usando la pseudo-elemento `::before` (me había ofuscado intentando hacerlo directamente, sin pensar en otras alternativas). Lo que hice fue:

- Usar el contenedor original como marco con un `overflow:hidden` para evitar que se vean los contenidos que exceden su tamaño.
- Agregar el pseudo-elemento `:before` que ocupe el 100% del tamaño del contenedor y que tenga como imagen de fondo la imagen que quiero con `background-size:cover`.
- Cuando el ratón pasa por encima del contenedor, hacer más grande el pseudo-elemento (cambiando la posición también) y el estilo `background-size:cover` se encargará del resto.

El resultado final quedó así:

```css
#gallery .squared { 
  height:0; 
  padding-top:50%; 
  position:relative; 
  overflow:hidden;
}

#gallery .squared::before {
  content: " ";
  position:absolute;
  background-size:cover;
  transition:all 0.25s linear;
  height:100%;
  width:100%;
  top:0;
  left:0;
}

#gallery .squared:hover:before {
  content: " ";  
  height:110%;
  width:110%;
  top:-5%;
  left:-5%;
}

.img0::before { background-image:url(http://lorempixel.com/300/200/people); }
.img1::before { background-image:url(http://lorempixel.com/300/300/nature); }
.img2::before { background-image:url(http://lorempixel.com/300/500/cats); }
.img3::before { background-image:url(http://lorempixel.com/500/300/sports); }
.img4::before { background-image:url(http://lorempixel.com/300/200/abstract); }
.img5::before { background-image:url(http://lorempixel.com/300/400/animals); }

#gallery .squared:hover { 
  background-size:110%; 
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
  #gallery .squared { padding-top:25%; }
}

@media (min-width: 992px) {
  #gallery .squared { padding-top:16.66%; }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<section id="gallery" class="section container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="squared col-xs-6 col-sm-3 col-md-2 img0"></div>
    <div class="squared col-xs-6 col-sm-3 col-md-2 img1"></div>
    <div class="squared col-xs-6 col-sm-3 col-md-2 img2"></div>
    <div class="squared col-xs-6 col-sm-3 col-md-2 img3"></div>
    <div class="squared col-xs-6 col-sm-3 col-md-2 img4"></div>
    <div class="squared col-xs-6 col-sm-3 col-md-2 img5"></div>
  </div>
</section>
```